# In vim, how to replace a pattern with multiple options, depending on a part of the original string?

Tags: vim, substitution

I would like to replace:

```
getLeftChild
getRightChild
```

with

```
leftchild
rightchild
```

I know how to do this in two pass: `:s/getLeftChild/leftchild/g` and `:s/getRightChild/rightchild/g`. But is there anything like `:s/get\(.*\)Child/<if \1 == "Left" then replace it with "left", else "right">child/g`?

Comment: I'd just do `:s/get//`with a `<C-v>j~`

Comment: @WayneWerner would you mind explain your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do the substitution in one shot, you can make use of the built-in `tolower()` function:

```
%s/\vget(.*Child)/\=tolower(submatch(1))/
```

You can adjust the search pattern for your real file.

Or you can use `\L` to do the lowercase substitution. (commented by @Meninx).

```
%s/\vget(.*Child)/\L\1/
```

Perhaps you want to check the difference between `\L and \l` and `\U and \u`

Comment: Another alternative for the answer above :  `%s/\vget(.*)/\L\1/`

Comment: @Meninx yes, that would be a good way too. I added in my answer, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar needs before. I *might* do

`:1,2s/get//` (well,  which would turn it into

```
1 LeftChild
2 RightChild
```

But I'm much more likely to do `<C-v><count>j$ugvV:s/^get//` (where `<count>` means something like 1 or 10) (though if it was a paragraph like this I would be more likely to use `v}` or perhaps `vip` to select the paragaph.

Comment: you need to add `%` to treat all the lines after `:`  in your first command ! `:%s/get` will also work !

Comment: There are chances that the word get appears alone or with other words like `getParent`, for example.

Comment: well, any range - which could be `line#,line#`, `mark,mark`, as you said, `%` for the whole file. Though typically for me I'd be highlighting the text I want, *mostly* because when it's highlighted I **know** I won't have any extra text in there.